# How to get top conversation from office 365 API response body

Tags: c#, json, string, office365api, tabular

I am trying to figure out how to get top/latest conversation from ongoing conversation. I am retrieving data from outlook office 365 API as JSON.
**JSON for email Body**

```
"Body": {
<html>
\r\n
<head>
</head>
<body lang=\"EN-US\" link=\"blue\" vlink=\"purple\">
\r\n<div class=\"WordSection1\">
    \r\n
    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">
            Hi Team,
        </span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        </span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<div>
        \r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
            <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">Thanks and Regards,</span>
        </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
            <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">Demo Person</span>
        </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
            <span style=\"font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:#E36C0A\">
                Team Demo
            </span><span style=\"font-size:9.0pt; color:#E36C0A\">
                - TSS\r\n
            </span>
            <span style=\"font-size:9.0pt; color:#F79646\">
                ASQT |dsfsf | &#43;919642739170
            </span><span style=\"font-size:9.0pt; color:#F79646\"></span>
        </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
            <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">
                <img width=\"163\" height=\"39\" id=\"Picture_x0020_1\" src=\"cid:image002.jpg@01D29C08.E3FC4D40\" alt=\"sign\">
            </span>
        </p>\r\n
    </div>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<div>
        \r\n
        <div style=\"border:none; border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt; padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in\">
            \r\n
            <p class=\"MsoNormal\">
                <b>From:</b> Demo Person
                <br>\r\n<b>Sent:</b> Monday, March 13, 2017 2:09 PM<br>\r\n<b>To:</b> Tempe@Email.com
                &lt;Temp1@email.com&gt;<br>\r\n<b>Cc:</b> Support@email.comt &lt;
                <br>\r\n<b>Subject:</b> RE: Demo Subject 1
            </p>\r\n
        </div>\r\n
    </div>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">&nbsp;</p>
    \r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">HI Demo Team,</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">
            Kindly check and confirm if you are working on this\r\n
        </span>
       </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
       </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">.</span>
       </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
       </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">

      </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">

    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\"></p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">
            &nbsp;
        </span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">
            Task assigned to you.
        </span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">Thanks &amp; Regards,</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">Demo,</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"color:#1F497D\">Sample Team</span></p>
    \r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<div>
        \r\n<div style=\"border:none; border-top:solid #E1E1E1 1.0pt; padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in\">
            \r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
                <b>From:</b> Temp person
                <br>\r\n<b>Sent:</b> Monday, March 13, 2017 1:13 PM<br>\r\n<b>To:</b> Demo person
                &lt;<a href=\"mailto:demp@email.com\">Demop@email.com.com</a>&gt;<br>
                \r\n<b>Cc:</b> Support@email.com &lt;<a href=\"mailto:Demo@email.com\">Demo@email.com</a>&gt;;
                <br>\r\n<b>Subject:</b> RE: Demo Subject 1
            </p>\r\n
        </div>\r\n
    </div>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">&nbsp;</p>\r\n
    <p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">Hi Demo,</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">&nbsp;</span>
    </p>\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\">
        <span style=\"color:#1F497D\">
            We are working on it.
        </span>
  </div>\r\n
  </body>\r\n
  </html>
  }
```

I wanted to get top record and search if there is any table in it. I think we can try by getting whole html body to a string and then check in that string with Regex. Will appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get top conversation by `Regex` and `string.Substring()`. Hope this will help someone in need.

```
//emailBody is a string variable
//Get the Index of first "From:"
int fromIndex = emailBody.Trim().IndexOf("From:");
if (fromIndex<0)//fromIndex will be -1 if it's fresh conversation
{
 //It's fresh conversation.
 //Reges.Replace will remove the unnecessary HTML tags before <body> tag 
 conversation = Regex.Replace(emailBody.Trim(), "[\\s\\S]*<body", "");
 //Do further action on topmost conversation.
}
else
{
 //It's ongoing conversation with more than one email.
 conversation = Regex.Replace(emailBody.Trim().Substring(0, fromIndex), "[\\s\\S]*<body", "");
 //Do further action on topmost conversation.
}
```

Note - I'm still working on how to get table from topmost conversation. I'll post shortly.